# Spam Classifier Clojure

Tags: machine-learning, clojure

I've been trying to implement spam classifier in Clojure. The reference book I've been using is Collective Intelligence. Here is the train method for training the classifier:

```
(defn train
  [t cat]
 (incc cat)
 (let [ws (keys (getwords t))]
 (for [w ws] (incf w cat))))
```

And here is my sampletrain method I wrote only to dump some training data into the classifier so that I dont have to train it every time manually.

```
(defn sampletrain
  []
    (do
       (train "Nobody owns the water." "good")
       (train "the quick rabit jumps fences" "good")
       (train "buy pharmaceuticals now" "bad")
       (train "make quick money at the online casino" "bad")
       (train "the quick brown fox jumps" "good")))
```

Unfortunately the sampletrain method only train my classifier with the last item or sentence "the quick brown fox jumps" classified as "good". At the end my classifier looks as follows:
{"the" {"good" 1}, "quick" {"goood" 1}, "brown" {"good" 1}, "fox" {"good" 1}, "jumps" {"good" 1}}. As you can see, It was only trained with last item. To avoid this I wrapped everything with "do" statement but I can't figure out why only the last call of "train" method was executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure uses implicit return and so does the `do` statement, so `train` is called for every sentence but you only return the value of the last expression evaluated. You could wrap it in a structure to return all of them.

Results wrapped in a vector:

```
(defn sampletrain
  []
  [(train "Nobody owns the water." "good")
   (train "the quick rabit jumps fences" "good")
   (train "buy pharmaceuticals now" "bad")
   (train "make quick money at the online casino" "bad")
   (train "the quick brown fox jumps" "good")])
```